# Maximum and minimum cardinality of R and S relation

Tags: database

Suppose that the cardinality of R and S relations are shown by CR and CS. What is the maximum and minimum cardinality of the following operation:

`R[A1, A2, ..., An] MINUS S`

Comment: Hi, this question belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @betontalpfa Hi, it's a database question not exactly math question, so it needs fundamental database comprehension.